# Mock My.User.IsInRole() error in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test to mock `My.User.IsInRole()` used in the following controller,

````
Public Class BookingController
    Public Function GetUserRole() As String
        If My.User.IsInRole("Agent") Then
             result = "Login as Agent"
        End If

        ```
    End Function
 End Class
````

trying to set up the mock in this test case (VB code):

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Test()
    //Arrange
    'Dim httpContext = New Mock(Of System.Web.HttpContextBase)()
    Dim principal = New Moq.Mock(Of IPrincipal)()

    'httpContext.Setup(Function(x) x.User).Returns(principal.[Object])
    principal.Setup(Function(p) p.IsInRole("Agent")).Returns(True)
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal.[Object]

    // Act
    Dim result = controller.GetUserRole()

End Sub
```

When calling `GetUserRole()`, `My.User.IsInRole("Agent")` should return `True`, but it returns `False`. Anything wrong on my code?

Any suggestion about this error.

Comment: Try setting it up with `p.IsInRole(It.IsAny(Of String)())` and see if that makes a difference. could be an issue with the encoding text being compared to.

Comment: You should also 
Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks. I tried using It.IsAny(..) specified in Moq Quickstart, but I got exception error: https://www.screencast.com/t/NT6Hzy6snmN

Comment: re-read the error message. You have a Sub when the call back in `Returns` requires a Function as it is expected to return a value

Comment: yes I realized to chnage to Function, but I got exception error: https://www.screencast.com/t/53fAt7sa

Comment: The original code is working if assigning principle mock to the current thread principle.

Comment: Ok glad you eventually got it working.

Comment: I just create another question to mock two principle objects, wonder if I can have your idea about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign principle mock to current thread principle, (Below is c# code I hope you can interpret it)

```
    // Make fack principle instance
    var fackPrinciple = new Mock<IPrinciple>();

    // Setup fack data
    fackPrinciple.Setup(e => e.IsInRole(It.IsAny<String>)).Returns(true);

    // Assign to current thread principle
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fackPrinciple.Object;
```

Please let me know if have any issue?

Comment: Excellent, it's working perfectly by assigning mock to current thread principle. Thanks very much @programtreasures.

Comment: I just created another question to mock two principle objects, it's working if I mock individual object, but not working for both principle mocking because the Current Principle can only be assigned to one mock object. Wonder if you have any idea about this. Thanks.

Comment: @Julia I have no Idea why you want to mock two principle object, but you cant do it.

Comment: I mock two principle because it's working on different members of principle, and now I am trying using one principle for both member functions, but it doesn't work.