# Mock My.User.IsInRole() and ClaimsPrincipal in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test to mock both My.User.IsInRole() and ClaimsPrincipal in the following controller.

The current thread principle has been assigned twice, therefore only the second ClaimPrincipal is working, how can I do to make both mock principle working?

```
Public Class TestController
   Public Function GetUserDetail() As String
       If My.User.IsInRole("Agent") Then
           result = "Login as Agent"
       End If

       If ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value = "user@hotmail.com" Then
           result = result & " and Claim name is correct"
       End If

       Return result
   End Function
End Class
```

trying to set up the mock in this test case (VB code, C# is ok too):

```
<TestMethod()>
 Public Sub Test()
    //Arrange

    //Mock User.IsInRole():
    Dim fakePrincipal = New Moq.Mock(Of IPrincipal)()
    fakePrincipal.Setup(Function(p) p.IsInRole("Agent")).Returns(True)
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fakePrincipal.[Object]

    'Dim fakeClaimPrincipal = New Mock(Of ClaimsPrincipal)()
    'Dim claims As IEnumerable(Of Claim) = New List(Of Claim) ().AsEnumerable()
    'fakeClaimPrincipal.Setup(Sub(e) e.Claims).Returns(claims)
    'Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fakeClaimPrincipal.[Object]

    //Mocking is not working on ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst(), so it's fixed 
      by using claim based function:

    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = New TestPrincipal(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user@hotmail.com"))

    Public Class TestPrincipal
        Inherits ClaimsPrincipal
        Public Sub New(ParamArray claims As Claim())
               MyBase.New(New TestIdentity(claims))
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class TestIdentity
         Inherits ClaimsIdentity
         Public Sub New(ParamArray claims As Claim())
                MyBase.New(claims)
         End Sub
    End Class

   // Act
   Dim result = TestController.GetUserDetail()

 End Sub
```

So one is mock principal, the other one is not mock principal, how do I assign the current thread?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock My.User.IsInRole() error in Asp.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117783/mock-my-user-isinrole-error-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

The second mock is overriding the first one that was set on the thread.

Use the mocked `ClaimsPrincipal` and setup necessary members

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Test()
    //Arrange    
    Dim fackClaimPrinciple = New Mock(Of ClaimsPrincipal)()        
    Dim claims As IEnumerable(Of Claim) = New List(Of Claim) ().AsEnumerable()
    fackClaimPrinciple.Setup(Sub(e) e.Claims).Returns(claims)
    fackClaimPrinciple.Setup(Function(p) p.IsInRole("Agent")).Returns(True)
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fackClaimPrinciple.[Object]

   // Act
   Dim result = TestController.GetUserDetail()

 End Sub
```

Comment: It's good to use one principal in this case. See the code change I made above, one is mock principal, the other one is not mock principal, is it possible to use one principal assigned to the current thread?